# Блокировки экрана & сворачивание приложения

Tags: android

Вопросы:

1. Как запретить блокировку экрана (автоматическую) как это сделано в играх
2. Если запущено приложение, в режиме выключенного экрана оно продолжает работать нормально или...?
3. Если свернуть приложение то будет что с ним будет, будет ли продолжать работу или будет Pause у процесса

Только начал программировать под Android и очень интересно именно это. Просто сейчас у меня приложение получает GPS координаты и отправляет их на сервер, но очень мучает вопрос: Что если заблокировать или свернуть приложение, GPS не будет отправлять координаты?. Это не вирус и не программа шпион, пишу для себя в целях обучения программированию Android просто решил выбрать именно эту задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. android:keepScreenOn="true"
2. Оно делает тоже, что и при сворачивании
3. Вызывается onPause(), а при включении onStart()

Comment: 3ий пункт это совет или автоматически делает приложение? если автоматически, то можно ли запретить onPause

Comment: Ну можно там ничего не написать, или как-то проверять в данном  случаи нужно исполнять данный код или нет.

Comment: Ещё в промежутке между onPause() и onStart() процесс может быть завершён, если система решит, что памяти мало.

Answer (score 0):

Если тебе нужно,чтобы приложение работало в свернутом состоянии ,то просто создай службу . Почитай на офф. сайте .   http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/services.html